# UWP thumbnail binding with image with x:bind

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, mvvm, binding

I am trying to bind thumbnail of my video StorageFile to Image XAML element through data template with x:Bind. I am using MVVM approach and I've used same method to achieve this in past but I don't know why it isn't working now.

I use live property explorer and source of Image is 0. other properties like video title are just working fine but image is not working. But problem occurs even with duration, sometimes duration shows up and sometimes it doesn't, which is odd.

I am providing my code below.

**Model**

```
public class VideoItem : LibraryItem
{
    #region Props
    public string Views { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Display { get; set; }
    public VideoProperties MyVideoProperties { get; set; }
    public StorageFile MyVideoFile { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public VideoItem(StorageFile File)
    {
        MyVideoFile = File;
        Initialize();
    }

    #region PrivateMethods
    private async void Initialize()
    {
        Title = MyVideoFile.DisplayName;
        MyVideoProperties = await MyVideoFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
        var dur = MyVideoProperties.Duration;
        Duration = $"{dur.Hours.ToString()} : {dur.Minutes.ToString()} : {dur.Seconds.ToString()}";
        Display = await GetDisplay();
        Views = MyVideoProperties.Rating.ToString();
    }

    private async Task<BitmapImage> GetDisplay()
    {
        var bitm = new BitmapImage();
        using (var imgSource = await MyVideoFile.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView))
        {
            if (imgSource != null) { bitm.SetSource(imgSource); }
            else
            {
                var storelogoFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
                var storageLogoFile = await storelogoFolder.GetFileAsync("StoreLogo.png");
                bitm.UriSource = new Uri(storageLogoFile.Path);
            }
        }
        return bitm;
    }
    #endregion

}

 public class LibraryItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class VideoLibraryViewModel
{
    #region Constructor
    public VideoLibraryViewModel(StorageFolder mainFolder)
    {

        VideoItems = new ObservableCollection<VideoItem>();
        MainFolder = mainFolder;
        Initialize();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Props
    public ObservableCollection<VideoItem> VideoItems { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region PrivateFields
    private StorageFolder MainFolder;
    private IEnumerable<StorageFile> Videos;
    private char[] sep = new char[] { '/' };
    #endregion

    #region PrivateMethods
    private async void Initialize()
    {

        Videos = await MainFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Videos = Videos.Where(a => a.ContentType.Split(sep)[0] == "video");
        FillUp();
    }

    private void FillUp()
    {

        foreach (var file in Videos)
        {
            VideoItems.Add(new VideoItem(file));
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

**View**

```
<controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="VideosLibraryGridView" Grid.Row="1"
                           Header="Videos"
                           Style="{StaticResource MainGridView}"
                           ItemClick="VideosLibraryGridView_ItemClicked"
                           ItemsSource="{x:Bind VideoLibraryVM.VideoItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="data:VideoItem">
                <StackPanel Margin="4" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Image  Source="{x:Bind Display, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource GridViewImage}"/>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource TimeBorder}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Duration, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title,Mode=OneWay}"  Style="{StaticResource GridViewVideoName}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Views,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource GridViewViews}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Views" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

**Style For Image**

```
 <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="GridViewImage">
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="UniformToFill"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

Output in the app, you can see gridview items show no image and no duration, sometimes duration show and image never shows up:

Why no image?

Why no duration?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have checked with breakpoints, all properties of items are appearing null, apart from title, all properties apart from title are retrieved asyncronosly, maybe that is the reason?

Comment: Not completely sure, as I've never used x:Bind, but you can try appending DataContext to the paths of your bindings.  x:Binds are compile time, and their behavior might be ... weird ... if they're in a DataTemplate rather than in the precompiled UI.  Wild ass guess, anyhow.

Comment: x bind is working on title , so it means it should also work on image

Comment: x:Bind looks fine. Can you check if it works by directly setting the path in XAML for Image.Source?

Comment: Also, can you try using `ImageSource` instead of `BitmapImage` in the View Model?

Comment: I have also tried that, direct path to an image works fine, but ImageSource in Viewmodel is not working either, I have checked with breakpoints, all properties of items are appearing null, apart from title, all properties apart from title are retrieved asyncronosly, maybe that is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

> all properties of items are appearing null, apart from title, all properties apart from title are retrieved asyncronosly

It's because the UI just render grid items with all available properties without waiting any results from asynchronous methods, hence why sometimes you'll get some items with a proper `duration` text shows up and sometimes It doesn't.

So, the logical solution is to run the asynchronous method **after** the gridview load those items, right?

But how? placing it under `loaded` event inside datatemplate doesn't change anything since It'll just do the same problem again.

well, you can do it by abusing `ContainerContentChanging` event inside Gridview control due to how that event itself works.

**Page.xaml**

```
<controls:AdaptiveGridView
    Name="VideosLibraryGridView" Grid.Row="1 
    ContainerContentChanging="VideosLibraryGridView_ContainerContentChanging"
    Header="Videos"
    Style="{StaticResource MainGridView}"
    ItemClick="VideosLibraryGridView_ItemClicked"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind VideoLibraryVM.VideoItems, Mode=OneWay}">
    <!--something something-->
</controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private void VideosLibraryGridView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args
{
    args.RegisterUpdateCallback(LoadImage);
}

private async void LoadImage(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
    var imageurl = (args.Item as model).ThumbnailUri;
    var cache = await getimagefromfileasync(imageurl);
    //check your image location based on your template first.
    var image = templateRoot.Children[0] as Image; 
    image.Source = new BitmapImage()
    {
        UriSource = new Uri(cache.Path)
    };
    image.Opacity = 1;
}
```

The code above is what I did in order to load the cached thumbnail asynchronously.

source:

1. [Dramatically Increase Performance when Users Interact with Large Amounts of Data in GridView and ListView](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-158/player#time=16m7s:paused)
2. [ContainerContentChanging Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.containercontentchanging)
3. [Update ListView and GridView items progressively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#update-listview-and-gridview-items-progressively)